# Redirect using Channels in Go

Tags: web-services, http, go

I am attempting to make a master program that redirects to servers in a round robin fashion. The master listens at port 9090 in this case and then redirects to either port 9001 or 9000. The idea is to have ports 9000 and 9001 held in a channel that is pulled from and added to by the redirect function. However, in practice it always redirects to 9000 rather than 9001. Is the channel not being updated correctly by the redirect function? or is there something else I am missing. The channel definitely has the values stored as I am successfully redirected from 9090 to 9000 every time.

Redirect function

```
func redirect(ports chan int) func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        channel := <-ports
        address := fmt.Sprintf("http://localhost:%d", channel)
        ports <- channel
        http.Redirect(w, r, address, 301)
    }
}
```

Master Main Function

```
func main() {
    currentChannel := make(chan int, 2)
    go startServer("C:/Users", "9000")
    go startServer("C:/Users", "9001")
    currentChannel <- 9000
    currentChannel <- 9001
    http.HandleFunc("/", redirect(currentChannel))
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

go startServer just starts a generic file server. I have tested each of them individually and I am able to access both 9000 and 9001 without the redirect with no problems.

Comment: It works for me. How are you determining that requests are not getting redirected properly?

Comment: This [program](https://play.golang.org/p/Irh4rAJgJkr) assigns ports using the same channel operations as in the question. It works as expected.  Something else is going on in your program.  I suggest logging `r.url.Path` and `channel` from the handler.  Random guess: the browser is requesting favicon.ico.

Comment: You two are right, my browser was caching and accessing the old page instead of requesting a new one and getting redirected again. Thank you.